# High-level concurrency à la STM in .NET (C#)?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, synchronization

I have the following problem in a project:

I have a REST API, whose threads I don't control explicitly; this API accesses internal resources/services. I would like to synchronize access to these resources, who may perform caching themselves. It is also necessary to prevent repeated triggering of expensive operations.

I think using an approach such as STM (à la Clojure or Haskell) would help a lot; currently, everything is using locks and it is getting really complicated. Unfortunately, Microsoft abandoned their STM implementation.

What are the .NET patterns for synchronized access over multiple resources? Are there any good libraries for this purpose? I'm looking for better and more high level solution then what locks bring to the table.